# Confusions about the system brightness under Android

Tags: android, range, max, min

Confusions about the system brightness under Android.
I use Android 10.0+ (R) with SDK 30.0.2.

The system brightness and its objects are documented in:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System#SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS

There is documented that the system brightness can be set in the range 0..255.

This is wrong!

As practical tests show, the adjustable range is significantly larger on many newer devices.

For example, on the "Xiaomi Mi 10" is the Range -> 10..2047.

But if limits are obviously variable, it should also be possible to determine the min and max for a meaningful setting.

Unfortunately I have not found a currently variant.

How can I read out the range for the system brightness?

Comment: were you able to find a correct solution for this?